# JAX-RS Jersey HTTP Status 404 The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource

Tags: java, rest, web-services, maven, jersey

---

I know that this question is asked too many times, but I have been stuck for like 3 hours on this and have tried a lot of ways to solve this by reading a lot of Stack Overflow posts and I came to a decision to submit a question here.

---

I am attaching my dependency list and the project structure and a part of my code that is used as a web service.

**Project Structure:**

### [image: Project structure]

**Dependencies:**

```
<groupId>survey</groupId>
<artifactId>survey</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/jstl -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
         <!--https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.mail/mail-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Apache Commons Codec -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-dbcp/commons-dbcp -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.22.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-http-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.22.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-http-client-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>1.22.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-services-oauth2</artifactId>
            <version>v2-rev120-1.22.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.22.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-services-plus</artifactId>
            <version>v1-rev453-1.22.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json used by sign in-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>LATEST</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.ws.rs/javax.ws.rs-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.jersey/jersey-server
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>1.19.1</version>
        </dependency>-->
        <!--Jersey container servlet-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>2.25.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.containers/jersey-container-servlet-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.25</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

**web.xml:**

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>survey.rest</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <!--<init-param>
        <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
        <param-value>survey.rest.SurveyResourceConfig</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>-->
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

**Class containing the restful web service with Jersey**

```
@Path("v1") public class SysAdminRest extends RestService {
@GET
@Path("/{sentBy}/{codeUn}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public void redirectToLoginPage(@PathParam("sentBy")int sentBy, @PathParam("codeUn") String code_un){
    Customer customer = null;
    try {
        customer = new SystemManager().getCustomerByCodeUN(code_un);

        request.setAttribute(Constants.CUSTOMER_OBJECT, customer);
        /*request.getServletContext()
                .getRequestDispatcher("survey/servlet/Survey.java").forward(request, response);*/

        request.getServletContext()
                .getRequestDispatcher("survey/servlet/survey").forward(request, response);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Now , when I deploy it to local host and make a get call at :

> http://localhost:8080/survey/v1/123456/1213141

the error i get is :

> HTTP Status 404 The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource

Is there anything that is wrong with my code or dependencies ?
Waiting for some answer thanks in advance.

Comment: I am not sure your url is correct. According to your web.xml, shouldn't it be like http://localhost:8080/rest/v1/123456/1213141

Comment: @yogidilip Based on my artifact id at pom.xml, I think it is correct, please correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: You need to definitely take in account of the <url-pattern> attribute in your web.xml. Without a matchng /rest/* -- your servlet won't get invoked. Try http://localhost:8080/survey/rest/v1/123456/1213141

Comment: I tested it, also tested http://localhost:8080/rest/v1/123456/1213141, but it is the same result. @yogidilip

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue?

Comment: Yes, it was a problem that I solved. @yogidilip

Comment: Please mentioned in the answer of how you solved this problem @HasS